# Filtering with Combo Boxes and SQL Using the MID Command

Tags: sql, database, vba, ms-access

I have tried and tried to get this peice of code working but with no luck.

The code is supposed to pick products that have the same sections of product code as cmbsource.

```
Private Sub cmbSource_AfterUpdate()

Dim Worktop As String

If ProductType = 1 Then

Worktop = "SELECT [products/stock].[Product Code], [products/stock].Description, [products/stock].[Stock Level] FROM [products/stock] " & _
"WHERE Category = 'DPALRC' " & _
"AND Mid('[Product Code]',1,5) = Mid('" & Me.cmbSource.Value & "',1,5) " & _
"AND Mid('[Product Code]',9,6) = Mid('" & Me.cmbSource.Value & "',9,6) " & _
"ORDER BY [Product Code];"

Me.cmbResult.rowSource = Worktop
Me.cmbResult = vbNullString

End If
```

Any Ideas?

Thanks in advance,
Bob P

Comment: make sure you issue a requery command for the cmbResult combobox, otherwise it will not update the items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Worktop = "SELECT [products/stock].[Product Code], [products/stock].Description, [products/stock].[Stock Level] FROM [products/stock] " & _
"WHERE Category = 'DPALRC' " & _
"AND Mid([Product Code],1,5) = Mid('" & Me.cmbSource.Value & "',1,5) " & _
"AND Mid([Product Code],9,6) = Mid('" & Me.cmbSource.Value & "',9,6) " & _
"ORDER BY [Product Code];"
```

This is my updated version, turns out the only error in the coding was having the single quotes around `[Product Code]`.

Answer (score 1):

Just a wild guess here.

```
Worktop = "SELECT ps.[Product Code], ps.Description, ps.[Stock Level]" & vbCrLf & _
"FROM [products/stock] AS ps" & vbCrLf & _
"WHERE ps.Category = 'DPALRC'" & vbCrLf & _
"AND Mid([Product Code],1,5) = '" & Mid(Me.cmbSource,1,5) & "'" & vbCrLf & _
"AND Mid([Product Code],9,6) = '" & Mid(Me.cmbSource,9,6) & "'" & vbCrLf & _
"ORDER BY ps.[Product Code];"
Debug.Print Worktop
```

Go to the Immediate window (<kbd>Ctrl+g</kbd>) and copy the statement from there.  Then create a new Access query, switch to SQL View, paste in the statement text, and run it.

If the code I suggested does not return the results you want, show us the actual SQL statement text and explain what is wrong with it.

Comment: This situation feels like `[Product Code]` may be some type of composite value whose parts could be split into separate fields.  That could make searching the data easier.  And when you need to see the pieces assembled as `[Product Code]`, just combine them in a query.

Comment: I agree Hans, however this database is not my own design :( I have been given it to unravel and understand as best I can, then develop it for a different kind of business. This means that `[Product Code]` is already tied into lots of other commands within other areas of access, so I can't break it down :( .